# How to specify union clause with generic unit of measure in F#?

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

Is there anyway to define a DU whose clauses uses generic unit of measure? e.g.

```
type MyDU =
| A  of int<_>
| B  of float<_>
```

this code doesn't compile, but I can specify a regular function that takes in a numeric value with generic unit of measure:

```
let f (n : int<_>) = n * n;;
val f : int<'u> -> int<'u ^ 2>
```

considering that each union clause is ultimately a function that converts the type specified after `of` to the private types `MyDU.A` or `MyDU.B` is there a particular reason why it works on function definition but not type definition?

Is there a way to do what I want to do here? If not, I would love to know why it wouldn't work too!

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a generic union -

```
type MyDU<[<Measure>] 't> =
    | A  of int<'t>
    | B  of float<'t>
```

This is beacause a `int<m>` is different to an `int<s>`.

Note that this is not specific to measure types, it also applies to things like using a union to create lists etc.